# Dereferencing a scalar reference in a hashref

Tags: perl, reference

I have a hashref with arrayrefs and scalarrefs as values. I can access the values of arrayrefs, but not the scalar refs.

```
foreach (keys %$data) {
  if (ref $data->{$_} eq 'ARRAY') { 
    push @values, $data->{$_}[0];
  }
  elsif (ref $data->{$_} eq 'SCALAR') { 
    push @values, $data->???
  }
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dereference a scalar reference, just preface the value with the scalar sigil, `$`:

```
if (ref $data->{$_} eq 'SCALAR') { 
    push @values, ${$data->{$_}};
}
```

Your arrayref case isn't quite right, as you are dereferencing to the first arrayref *element*, rather than getting all elements of the array. However, since you are storing a scalar, you can't store all the arrayref's values, unless you transformed them to a scalar in some fashion -- say, getting the number of elements in that arrayref (which is what you get when you evaluate an array in scalar context), or by concatenating all the array elements together into a string.

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References):

> Using References
>
> 1. Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a simple scalar variable containing a reference of the correct type:
>
> ```
> $bar = $$scalarref;
> push(@$arrayref, $filename);
> $$arrayref[0] = "January";
> $$hashref{"KEY"} = "VALUE";
> &$coderef(1,2,3);
> print $globref "output\n";
> ```
>
> It's important to understand that we are specifically not dereferencing $arrayref[0] or $hashref{"KEY"} there.  The dereference of the scalar variable happens before it does any key lookups.  Anything more complicated than a simple scalar variable must use methods 2 or 3 [below].  However, a "simple scalar" includes an identifier that itself uses method 1 recursively.  Therefore, the following prints "howdy".
>
> ```
> $refrefref = \\\"howdy";
> print $$$$refrefref;
> ```

Comment: Thanks! As for your other concerns, I guess it looks wrong without context, but in this particular piece of the code I only need the first element of the arrayref pushed into @values. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned with the values of `%$data`, you can loop over them instead of the keys:

```
for my $value (values %$data) {
    if (ref $value eq 'ARRAY') {
        push @values, $value->[0];
    } elsif (ref $value eq 'SCALAR') {
        push @values, $$value;
    }
}
```

More concise and readable, IMHO.